# Update a property of a component from the parent

Tags: reactjs, properties, parent-child

I have been trying to change the property of a child but failing. I have tried most of the lifecycle methods of react yet none of them seemed to work (didMount propsUpdate etc).

Any help would be appreciated

http://codepen.io/yogainalift/pen/KMPvNz

```
var Field = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      message: this.props.setMessage || 'should change this one'
    }
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.message}
      </div>
    )
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      inputField: ''
    }
  },

  handle(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.setState({
      inputField: event.target.value
    })
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type='text' placeholder='changing this text' onChange={this.handle}/>
        <Field setMessage={this.state.inputField} />
      </div>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood from your question, you are trying to have Field render the same as the input, am I right?

Your Field component is using state to render its content on

```
<div>
     {this.state.message}
</div>
```

You should use

```
<div>
    {this.props.setMessage}
</div>
```

You could also use [componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops) lifecycle method to set a new state for Field.
Code would look like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
  this.setState({
    message: nextProps.setMessage || 'should change this one'
  });
}
```

Hope it helps.